# i3: Firefox opens window on inactive workspace

Tags: i3, workspaces, user-interface

I encountered a weird behavior with Firefox in i3. It sometimes opens on random inactive workspace, which is kind of annoying. I have no customization regarding Firefox in my i3 config. I have no idea, why this happens or how can I debug it.

I suspect it may be related to switching on and off the additional monitor using `arandr` or switching to and back from another user, but I can't quite reproduce it. It doesn't seem to occur with any other application, but that may be affected by my behavior (I keep my terminals open, but I close Firefox and open it usually as first, when I get back to computer).

I know I can use `assign`, but I'd like to avoid that.

Edit:

- I noticed that Firefox opens at active workspace and then switches to one of inactive ones.