# Make firefox open url in currently selected virtual desktop

Tags: kde, firefox, desktop, virtual-desktop

Recently, i tried to organize my computer using KDE's virtual desktops, so windows that i open on my gaming desktop do not disturb me when i'm on my working desktop.
But there is a problem with firefox (that i use as a navigator), which **always opens url request in most recently active window**.

For example, when i have one firefox window in Desktop 1, one other window in Desktop 2, if i select Desktop 1's firefox window, i switch to Desktop 2 *without selecting its firefox window* and i open a link in another application, the tab will open to Desktop 1's window and will switch me to Desktop 1.

What i would like is that when i click on a link while on Desktop k:

- If no firefox window is in Desktop k, open one with the url
- If there is one (or more) windows in Desktop k, open the url on the most recently active firefox window **from Desktop k**.

Is there a way to achieve this. I've looked up forums and found that i should edit firefox's option `widget.disable-workspace-management` to true, but it does not seem to change anything. Also, the problem seems similar to what can be found in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634633/i3-firefox-opens-window-on-inactive-workspace), but i am not using i3 and my problem is more specific.

I am looking for either a parameter *inside* firefox, or for a config file to edit to program the specific behaviour i described (but i have no idea which file i could edit).

PS: My computer is running Debian 11 (bullseye) with KDE 5.78.0 with firefox 102.10.0esr